# Image source is not getting value at runtime in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, image, upload

I am using `ng-src` to display uploaded image in a circle at the time of image upload.  I am using an object  `$scope.Customer.CU_ProfilePicture` which is used to store the link of image
I am getting data if an image  `/Resources/4bd355d8-731c-4a64-b898-93bec6a7ae8e.png`
and using

```
 <img title="logoImg" src="{{Customer.CU_ProfilePicture}}"  ng-src="{{Customer.CU_ProfilePicture!=''?Customer.CU_ProfilePicture:'/images/user.png'}}" alt="Image" />
```

To bind the image but not getting the value of data in image src.
[image]

I am attaching thevalue of data which i am getting in Customer.CU_ProfilePicture.[image]

Comment: Use bracket Notation $scope.Customer['CU_ProfilePicture']

Comment: no solution is still not working